# Can you turn only one page into an app in meteor?

Tags: ios, meteor

I have just tried to run

```
meteor run ios
```

That command emulates my application as an app. But there is just one page that would be interesting to have as an app. Can you control this in some way?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible. The whole app gets exported regardless of platform, hence the universal/isomorphic apps concept. And in the universal app concept is one that I'm starting to find fault in. That said there is a better middle ground.

We'll call it **sudo-universal apps.** (probably a horrible name, but whatever :D)
Essentially the concept is that you have 3 codebases, for each device (web/ios/andriod) but share many of the same modules via something like npm, or potentially some other way of sharing code.

Then you can focus on the ui for each device and its strengths and weaknesses, but keep all the important logic you've built.

Check out the following:

- https://voice.kadira.io/say-no-to-isomorphic-apps-b7b7c419c634#.3bn5ovts1
- https://forums.meteor.com/t/say-no-to-universal-apps/16813/7

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! Interesting. I have friend who manage to do it with one code base, but as I understood that was not easy. And in my case I think I will get quite far just by learning how to do the pages responsive.

Comment: Yeah I honestly say if your app is not that big, than one responsive app would be just fine. You could always pull it apart later if need be :)

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether the client code is executed on iOS or not, and change the app accordingly:

```
if(navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPad|iPhone|iPod)/g)) {
   // Disable the links, and redirect to which page you want
}
```

But Justin's answer is great, a new platform usually needs more than just some tweaks. A quickly developed app has very low value for the user.